# Orientation for Preview: Create Tablet Variation missing

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm learning the basics of Kotlin development from a book, which tells me I should press the "Orientation for Preview" button and then the "Create Tablet Variation" choice. Unfortunately only options I can see are "Portrait", "Landscape" and "UI Mode". I'm using Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1. When I look at the source code of the example application, it appears a folder named layout-sw600dp will be created in the res folder at some point. Is my version of Android Studio broken or do I have an incorrect setting in Android Studio or is it intentional there is no longer a "Create Tablet Variation" choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it intentional there is no longer a "Create Tablet Variation" choice?

Presumably yes. Adjacent to that "Orientation for Preview" button you will find a drop-down to choose a device profile to use for the preview. You can choose a tablet from "Generic devices" or create a specific screen definition as you see fit.